# BR tag between inputs wont make line breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a row of inputs (from type `button`) and I want to create a line space between every 3.
So I make this:

```js
for(var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
  if(i%3 == 0) $('#input' + i).before('<br>');
}
```

the buttons stay in their position. image:
[image]

ideas anyone?

**Edit:**

The problem was in the CSS, I set the `display` of the main div as `inline-grid`. Thanks for everyone that try help.

Comment: You mean line breaks?

Comment: @ellipsis that true.

Comment: @Dasmond Why are you starting at `index = 1` and not `index  = 0`?

Comment: @nickzoum because my buttons are `input1` and up not from zero

Comment: @Dasmond do all the buttons have ids like `input1`, `input2` and so on?

Comment: @Dasmond it works for me https://jsfiddle.net/8hrwnesb/2/ - can you try to reproduce your problem in this fiddle?

Comment: @Xatenev yes I try now.

Comment: @Dasmond check my edits

Comment: @Xatenev maybe my design is the problem? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h4xw27ny/) Its works here but in my page not.

Comment: @Dasmond Yes probably its either your HTML structure or other CSS attributes. You can try to add the surrounding html & css structure into the fiddle and see if you can get a reproducible state

Comment: @freedomn-m I know that, I've brought what's needed - and the fact is that these generous people are helping me.

Comment: I agree that people are very helpful.  But for prosperity, you can't rely on jsfiddle and the fact is your question doesn't include all the required html/css/js to *reproduce* the issue, as shown by the first fiddle comment "it works for me".  I tend to include the reason for close vote as a comment rather than just close/down vote, in an attempt to be transparent.  **It's not my wording, it's SO's policy.**

Comment: @freedomn-m all good my friend, you`re right. in any case - I have solved the problem.

Comment: Also glad that you have it all sorted.  One of the problems answering questions like this is finding exactly what's causing the problem.  You would not have asked this question given just that code as you, yourself, can see it *should* work.  It's why we recommend creating an [mcve] (in the question) as this can quite often let the questioner find the issue in the process of making the mcve. :)

Answer (score 1):

append the `<br>` after the `button` not before it.

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
  if (i % 3 == 0)
    $('#input' + i).after('<br>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="input1">a</button>
<button id="input2">b</button>
<button id="input3">c</button>
<button id="input4">d</button>
<button id="input5">e</button>
<button id="input6">f</button>
<button id="input7">g</button>
<button id="input8">h</button>
<button id="input9">i</button>
```

Comment: I don't think this answers OP's question because he said the <br> tag wont make line breaks. If that is the case, your answer wont fix that.

Comment: I will explain the question again - it does place the `<br>` in its place but does not create a line break.

Comment: check the edits

Comment: maybe my design is the problem? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h4xw27ny/) Its works here but in my page not.

Comment: maybe some applied css will be interfering to the buttons or their parent element

Comment: @ellipsis Oh, I dont believe. the problem its because I set the main div of this `inputs` to be `display:inline-flex` - but, I need to show them inline instead of line breaks. which display will be correct?

Comment: Did you try `display:inline` ?

Comment: Use `display:inline`

Answer (score 1):

I want to bring CSS Grid into the mix, because...2019.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="button" id="input0">
  <input type="button" id="input1">
  <input type="button" id="input2">
  <input type="button" id="input3">
  <input type="button" id="input4">
  <input type="button" id="input5">
  <input type="button" id="input6">
  <input type="button" id="input7">
  <input type="button" id="input8">
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/910mc24f/3/)

Comment: Its the first time I have see this method. but in fact I gave the number `3` as example. the number changed every couple minutes by jquery calculate.

Comment: @Dasmond What do you mean? This is pure CSS and has nothing to do with jQuery or even JavaScript.

Comment: I understand that but its not suitable for the problem I had. Thanks for trying!